# I need help with this error

Tags: callbacks

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'uthan_preloader' not found or invalid function name in /home/u815400924/domains/jardineschapa.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 308
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if any function with the name `uthan_preloader` exists in your active theme/plugins.

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is somewhere in theme/plugins, that function is called either via `add_action` or `add_filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your themes and plugins for the string `uthan_preloader`.
There is likely a hook or filter somewhere that calls the function above, but the function does not (or no longer) exists.

An example of how that could come to be: maybe it was part of a plugin that got deactivated but is still referenced in your theme.

Depending on your setup, you may want to download your site's *wp-content* folder (e.g. via FTP) and then use a tool like Notepad++ to search across all files.